# Can this be done without Quasi Quoter?

Tags: haskell

I have a tiny DSL that actually works quite well. When I say

```
import language.CWMWL

main = runCWMWL $ do
    out (matrixMult, A, 1, row, 1 3 44 6 7)
```

then `runCWMWL` is a function that is exported by `language.CWMWL`. This parses the experession and takes some action.

What I want to achieve is that there is some way to repeat this e.g. 1000 times and have the third element of the tuple consisting the numbers 1 to 1000. My own DSL is not complete enough to do this. Eventually I want to change the string in the last element as well.

Is there any possibility to do this without Quasi Quotes? Are Quasi Quotes the best tool for this?

What binops / primitives would my DSL need to contain or need to wrap in order to allow this in an elegant way?

Comment: what's going on syntactically in the last field of that tuple?

Comment: A space delimeted list.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, I don't think quasiquotation will get you something much nicer than

```
main = runCWMWL $
    sequence [ out (matrixMult, A, n, row, 1 3 44 6 7) | n <- [1..1000] ]
```

You might also look into [`MonadComprehensions`](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/MonadComprehensions) as well as [`RebindableSyntax`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#rebindable-syntax) for other ideas.

Comment: ...well, actually I suppose a quasiquotation solution would expand at compile time, whereas I don't know how much evaluation GHC would do to the above.

Comment: You are right with everything of course. A second way would be to extend the DSL accordingly but I currently do not see what binops and primitives would need to be added. I edited the question.